# Confused about recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void SingSongFor(int numberOfBottles){

    if (numberOfBottles == 0){
        printf("There are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n");
    } else {
        
        printf("%d bottles of beer on the wall. %d bottles of beer.\n", numberOfBottles, numberOfBottles);
        
        int oneFewer = numberOfBottles - 1;
        printf("Take one down, pass it around, %d bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n", oneFewer);
        
        SingSongFor(oneFewer); // This function calls itself!
        
        // Print a message just before the function ends
        printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n",numberOfBottles);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  
    // We could sing 99 verses, but 4 is easier to think about
    SingSongFor(4);
    
    return 0;
}
```

According to my understanding the program must terminate after it prints:

> There are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall.

But how come it resumes to print:

> Put a bottle in the recycling, 1 empty bottles in the bin.
>
> Put a bottle in the recycling, 2 empty bottles in the bin.
>
> Put a bottle in the recycling, 3 empty bottles in the bin.
>
> Put a bottle in the recycling, 4 empty bottles in the bin.

The if functions already printed out a message, but instead of terminating it gets to the else as well. How is this possible? And How is there a increment from 1 to 4 in "numberOfBottles"?

Update : This is my understanding of the code. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, just your output is derpy.

Comment: each time the recursed called function exits, the caller resumes execution after the recursive call and the only thing left to execute is the printf about bottles in the recycle bin.

Comment: number of bottles in the last printf statement is using the parameter passed to its' instance of the recursive function  In the recursive calls the number is counting down, but in the stepping out of the recursion, the passed in parameter is successively higher.

Comment: @user3629249 How does numberOfBottles start at 1 and not 0?

Comment: @DanteGreyson: Why should it start at 0? When `numberOfBottles` equals 0 only the true block of the `if` is executed and the recursion bottoms-out, so control passes to the statement following the `SingSongFor(0)` call, where `numberOfBottles` equals 1.

Comment: Related: [tail recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33923/90527).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To understand why your program acts as it does, it's necessary to understand how a function call works. The fact that it's recursive might enable the compiler to make some optimizations that improve the efficiency of the program, but conceptually being recursive doesn't really change what is happening.

First, let's examine an alternative program that does basically the same thing as your program, using non-recursive function calls.

```
void SingSongFor4(){

        printf("4 bottles of beer on the wall. 4 bottles of beer.\n");

        printf("Take one down, pass it around, 3 bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n");

        SingSongFor3();

        // Print a message just before the function ends
        printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, 4 empty bottles in the bin.\n");
    }
}

void SingSongFor3(){

        printf("3 bottles of beer on the wall. 3 bottles of beer.\n");

        printf("Take one down, pass it around, 2 bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n");

        SingSongFor2();

        // Print a message just before the function ends
        printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, 3 empty bottles in the bin.\n");
    }
}

void SingSongFor2(){

        printf("2 bottles of beer on the wall. 2 bottles of beer.\n");

        printf("Take one down, pass it around, 1 bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n");

        SingSongFor1();

        // Print a message just before the function ends
        printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, 2 empty bottles in the bin.\n");
    }
}

void SingSongFor1(){

        printf("1 bottles of beer on the wall. 1 bottles of beer.\n");

        printf("Take one down, pass it around, 0 bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n");


        printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, 1 empty bottles in the bin.\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    // We could sing 99 verses, but 4 is easier to think about
    SingSongFor4();

    return 0;
}
```

I hope that it's obvious that each function prints a couple of lines, calls the next function, then prints another line.  Each called function does this in turn so, for example, 2 lines for `SingSongFor4()` are printed, then `SingSongFor3` is called. This prints its 2 lines, then calls `SingSongFor2()`, which prints its lines and so forth. `SingSongFor1()` doesn't call any other functions so it prints all three lines then returns to `SingSongFor2()` which completes and so on up the chain.  In all you get the 8 lines of `X bottles on the wall/take one down` as you follow the function calls "down", then the 4 lines of "Put a bottle in the bin" as you return "up" the reverse direction.

Your function isn't any different except that it's been parameterized and had a little logic added to determine when it should act like `SingSongFor1()` and when it should act like the other 3.  I say it's not different except that in your case you have a single copy of the text of the program that's shared by each invocation of the program rather than 4 separate (nearly identical) copies of the text. What makes it possible to share a copy of the text is the local context of each function call - the parameters, variables, and some housekeeping information about where the program lives and the state of execution of the program.

Typically this context information is contained in a special data structure called the stack. It's called a stack because you stack things one on top of the other, then remove them one at a time from the "top."  Each stack frame contains the context of one invocation of the function: the parameters - in your case `numberOfBottles`; the local variables - `oneFewer`; and information about which statement should be executed when the function ends or returns.  When a function is called the frame corresponding to that call is pushed onto the stack and the text of the function is executed.  When it finishes, the frame is popped off and execution resumes in the calling function at the point where it left off (which was stored in the popped off stack frame for this purpose). It resumes using the new "top" frame of the stack for it's context.

The important thing, though, is that your recursive function works exactly the same way as any other function - each time it's called it gets a new context of its very own, even though the text of the function is the same.  It executes to completion then returns to the previous context - which may have been the same function, though with a different context.

Answer (score 20):

3 bottles:

```
SingSong(3):
 PRINT 2 LINES
 SingSong(2):
     PRINT 2 LINES
     SingSong(1):
          PRINT 2 LINES
          SingSong(0):
               PRINT 1 LINES
          PRINT RECYCLE LINE
     PRINT RECYCLE LINE
 PRINT RECYCLE LINE
```

After your final inner recursive call happens, it then backs its way out through each method call and calls the recycling message.

Answer (score 6):

The recursive function calls are *stacked*. So it goes something like this:

```
SingSongFor(4)
  |
  v
SingSongFor(3)
  |
  v
SingSongFor(2)
  |
  v
SingSongFor(1)
  |
  v
SingSongFor(0)
```

The last call prints that there are no more bottles and then returns and this is there the *magic* happens: It returns to the *previous* call, which will then print the message about the recycling bin, and return to the *previous* call which again print its message, and so on.

Comment: I dislike that you refer to it as magic. It's not, it's simply returning from a function - like any other function. It only seems like magic if you don't understand that each invocation of a function has it's own context (parameters and local variables). It would work the same if there were 99 separate `SingSongForX()` functions that were called in turn, though in that case you'd have both a separate text (code) and a separate context (parameters and local variables).  Explaining the concept of the separation of code and context is more helpful than calling it magic.

Comment: @tvanfosson I always thought that expression was used to signify the most noteworthy/interesting part of a phenomenon, not that it's somehow incomprehensible.

Answer (score 4):

After the line

```
 SingSongFor(oneFewer); // This function calls itself
```

You have a printf i.e.

```
 printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n",numberOfBottles);
```

So that is what the program does. With the value of `numberOfBottles` that is stored on the stack.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is just right. When you reach the final message `There are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall.` your program returns to the point where it was called (it was called in function `SingSongFor` with argument `1`). Then prints the message `Put a bottle in the recycling, 1 empty bottles in the bin.` and returns to previous call in function `SingSongFor` with argument `2`. And like this up to 4.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's derpy is because you're calling the next function BEFORE you print the number of bottles in the current function. So when it all catches up, the last function prints first.

Currently:

```
    SingSongFor(oneFewer); // This function calls itself!
    // Print a message just before the function ends
    printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n",numberOfBottles);
```

What you Want:

```
    // Print a message just before the function ends
    printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n",numberOfBottles);
    SingSongFor(oneFewer); // This function calls itself!
```

That way, you'll get the output you expect and THEN the next step-down happens.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you only want to print the total in the recycle bin once when the recursion completes, then the easiest solution is to use a `wrapper` (or helper) function to call `SingSonfFor`. By using a wrapper, you preserve the original `numberOfBottles` as the count for the recycle, while each bit of recursion will reduce the number by one. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void SingSongFor (int numberOfBottles){

    if (!numberOfBottles)
        return;

    int oneFewer = numberOfBottles - 1;

    printf (" %d bottles of beer on the wall. %d bottles of beer.\n", 
            numberOfBottles, numberOfBottles);

    printf (" Take one down, pass it around, %d bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n", 
            oneFewer);

    if ((oneFewer) == 0)
        printf (" There are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall.\n\n");
    else 
        SingSongFor (oneFewer); // This function calls itself!
}

void ss_helper (int numberOfBottles)
{
    SingSongFor (numberOfBottles);

    /* Print a message just before the function ends */
    printf(" Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n",
        numberOfBottles);

    if (numberOfBottles >= 6)
        printf ("\n Now go sober up you lush...\n\n");
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    // We could sing 99 verses, but 4 is easier to think about
    int coldbeers = (argc > 1) ? atoi (argv[1]) : 4;
    // SingSongFor (coldbeers);
    ss_helper (coldbeers);

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/beersong
 4 bottles of beer on the wall. 4 bottles of beer.
 Take one down, pass it around, 3 bottles of beer on the wall.

 3 bottles of beer on the wall. 3 bottles of beer.
 Take one down, pass it around, 2 bottles of beer on the wall.

 2 bottles of beer on the wall. 2 bottles of beer.
 Take one down, pass it around, 1 bottles of beer on the wall.

 1 bottles of beer on the wall. 1 bottles of beer.
 Take one down, pass it around, 0 bottles of beer on the wall.

 There are simply no more bottles of beer on the wall.

 Put a bottle in the recycling, 4 empty bottles in the bin.
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
    SingSongFor(oneFewer); // This function calls itself!

    // Print a message just before the function ends
    printf("Put a bottle in the recycling, %d empty bottles in the bin.\n",numberOfBottles);
```

The call to the `SingSongFor` function **does not return until it has completed** (and all the child functions which it called have also completed).

So the `printf` line is **forced to wait** until *all* the lower `SingSongFor` calls have finished, before it will run.

In other words, calling a function does not queue it up for execution in future, it runs that function *immediately*, and **execution of the current function is paused** until the called function has finished.

This process is why function calls create a ***stack*** of execution states, with each stack entry holding the local values that will be needed when execution at that level resumes (in this case, just the `numberOfBottles` variable, and the memory address of the next instruction to that is waiting to run).

This pushing and popping of stack entries can make recursion (briefly) consume a lot of memory, and in the worse case, when the stack fills up too much memory, this can result in ... a **stack overflow**!